# Strange behavior with keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui

I have a javascript code to implement Jquery Calendar and a keypress event to open the calendar when I press enter key.

This first code works good except enter key in chrome (if i press another key in chrome the event fire)

```
        function ImproveDateTextBoxs() {
            $("img[id*=DatePickerImage]").closest(".ms-dtinput").remove();
            $(".ms-dtinput input[id$='Date']").each(function () {
                ImproveDate($(this));
                $($(this).next('img')).wrap($("<A/>").attr("href","#"));



            });
        }

        function ImproveDate(obj) {

//          obj.focus(function () { obj.select(); });

            if (typeof jQuery.ui.datepicker != "undefined") {
                obj.datepicker({
                    showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: '/_layouts/images/calendar.GIF',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                        selectOtherMonths: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function() {
                        $(this).next('a').focus(); 
                    }               
                });
                obj.next('a').keypress(function (e) {
                 var key = e.which;
                 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
                  {
//                  e.preventDefault();
//                  console.log("hola");
                    $(this).children().click();
                    return false;  
                  }
                });
//          obj.parent().next().children("a").removeAttr('onclick');
//          obj.parent().next().children("a").click(function () { obj.select(); });
            }
        }
```

The following code open calendar and immediately hid again (and the same problem in chrome)

```
        //Datepicker jquery ui
        function ImproveDateTextBoxs() {
            $("img[id*=DatePickerImage]").closest(".ms-dtinput").remove();
            $(".ms-dtinput input[id$='Date']").each(function () {
                ImproveDate($(this));
                $($(this).next('img')).wrap($("<A/>").attr("href","#"));
                $(this).next('a').keypress(function (e) {
                 var key = e.which;
                 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
                  {
//                  e.preventDefault();
//                  console.log("hola");
                    $(this).children().click();
                    return false;  
                  }
                });


            });
        }

        function ImproveDate(obj) {

//          obj.focus(function () { obj.select(); });

            if (typeof jQuery.ui.datepicker != "undefined") {
                obj.datepicker({
                    showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: '/_layouts/images/calendar.GIF',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                        selectOtherMonths: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function() {
                        $(this).next('a').focus(); 
                    }               
                });

//          obj.parent().next().children("a").removeAttr('onclick');
//          obj.parent().next().children("a").click(function () { obj.select(); });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle?  A couple of possible guesses though: If I recall correctly keypress doesn't fire for all keys, but keyup and keydown do.  Instead of preventDefault, maybe look into [event].stopPropegation